# dynamically add span around angularjs data

Tags: angularjs

Currently I'm reading data from an input field that gets pushed into an object in the controller, the data is then displayed in the view as following:

```
<ul class="status_list">
  <li data-ng-repeat="comment in comments" class="status">
    {{ comment.data }}
  </li>
</ul
```

I want to make it so if `comment.data` contains `#word`, it's replaced with `<span class='x'>#word</span>`. But I'm not quite sure how to:
1) search through the data in the view 
2) append html to it

Comment: Do you mean do a text search through the string assigned to comment.data and replace it with some other string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider dynamically adding the spans via Javascript, then using `ng-bind-html-unsafe` to bind that value to your view.

1) Create a method on $scope to do the text replacement.

```
$scope.GetDataWithHtml = function() {
   return $scope.comment.data.replace(/\#word/gi, '<span>$1</span>');
};
```

2) In your `<ul>`, bind as follows:

```
<dul class="status_list">
  <li data-ng-repeat="comment in comments" class="status" ng-bind-html-unsafe="GetDataWithHtml()"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a custom filter.

```
app.filter("AddSpan", function() {
  return function(item) {

    if (item.indexOf("#word") > -1) {
      return "<span class='x'>" + item + "</span>";
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  }
});
```

Because you're adding HTML dynamically you also need to tell Angular to bind it 'unsafely' rather than escaping the HTML as it will do by default.

```
  <li data-ng-repeat="comment in comments" class="status" ng-bind-html-unsafe="comment.data | AddSpan"></li>
```

IMO this is a cleaner solution than adding a method to $scope - I don't think HTML belongs in the controller, and filters are designed for cases just like this when you just want to modify the appearance of the data.

Comment: whao this return function is trippy, I modified the code so there's an alert(); before the return function(..) call and it only runs the first time, and skips it thereafter, does this mean the filter "AddSpan" function isn't being called everytime and angular just puts the filter function on a global stack for reference?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a filter.  {{ comment.data | mkSpan }}

```
angular.module('myapp.filters', [])
    .filter('mkSpan', function () {
        return function (input,klass) {
            if(angular.isDefined(input)){
                return (angular.isDefined(klass)) ? '<span class="' + klass + '">' + input + '</span>' : '<span>' + input + '</span>';
            }
            return input;
        }
}); // end mkSpan / myapp.filters

angular.module('myapp',['myapp.filters']);
```

{{ comment.data | mkSpan:myCssClass }}

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this question more recently, here is an updated version of @mikel's answer (`ng-bind-html-unsafe` has been deprecated since angular v 1.2.0). Instead, you have to mark the html as trusted and use `ng-bind-html`.

The following custom filter will add a span to all hashtags (coffeescript):

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
.filter('pxnHashtagHighlight', ($sce)->
  (value)->
    hashtags = /(?:^|\s)(#(\w+))/gm
    $sce.trustAsHtml(value.replace(hashtags, ' <span class="tag">$1</span>'))
)
```

Which can be used with the following markup (jade):

```
div.example(ng-bind-html="comment.data | pxnHashtagHighlight")
```

**Notes**

- Because we want to add html we can't use plain `ng-bind` or the `{{  }}` shorthand.
- This method is dependent on `$sce` to mark the html as trusted. In newer android versions this has been removed from core into the `ngSanitise` module, so you'll have to download that and add it as a dependency for your app.